# How to get table data which is in different frames excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, html-table

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Dim fRD As Long, i As Long, fSR As Long, j As Long
Dim pID As String
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim urL As String
Dim fnd As Boolean
Dim hiddenPID
Dim elemColl
Dim elemCOllection
Dim r As Long, t As Long, c As Long

Sub genOP()

With RD

    fRD = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    urL = "http://eringcapture.jccal.org/caportal/CAPortal_MainPage.aspx"

    For i = 2 To 2

        fSR = SR.Range("A" & SR.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        pID = Trim(Format(.Range("A" & i).Value, "0"))    ' get PID

        If Len(pID) < 8 Then GoTo nextRow

        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate urL

        Call WaitForIE
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementById("RealSearchLink").Click
        Call WaitForIE
        Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementById("SearchByParcel").Checked = True

        'SearchByTB
        'Delete the first 2 digits from the excel data (parcel ID), e.g. 22002240080330000000 (instead of 0122002240080330000000)
        pID = Mid(pID, 2, 16)

        Call EnterIDSubmit
        Call WaitForIE

        If Trim(Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementById("TotalRecFound").innerText) <> "No Records Found." Then

            'Result Found
            Set elemColl = Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("Header1Font")
            elemColl(0).Click
            Call WaitForIE

            SR.Range("A" & fSR) = Trim(Format(.Range("A" & i).Value, "0"))
            SR.Range("B" & fSR) = hiddenPID

            'id = MainTable
            'Set elemCOllection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
            TEMP.Cells.Clear

            'Set elemCOllection = Doc.getElementById("Iframe2").contentDocument.getElementById("MainTable")
            'Set elemCOllection = Doc.getElementById("Iframe2").contentDocument.getElementById("MainTable")
            r = 1
            For Each elemColl In Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").getElementsByTagName("td")
                TEMP.Cells(r, 0).Value = elemColl.innerText
                r = r + 1
            Next

'            For t = 0 To (elemCOllection.Length - 1)
'                For r = 0 To (elemCOllection(t).Rows.Length - 1)
'                    For c = 0 To (elemCOllection(t).Rows(r).Cells.Length - 1)
'                        TEMP.Cells(r + 1, c + 1) = elemCOllection(t).Rows(r).Cells(c).innerText
'                    Next c
'                Next r
'            Next t


            Stop
        Else
            'Result Not Found
            SR.Range("A" & fSR) = "No Records Found"
        End If



nextRow:
    Next i

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End With

MsgBox "Process Completed"

End Sub

Sub EnterIDSubmit()

hiddenPID = Left(pID, 2) & " " & Mid(pID, 3, 2) & " " & _
    Mid(pID, 5, 2) & " " & _
    Mid(pID, 7, 1) & " " & Mid(pID, 8, 3) & " " & _
    Mid(pID, 11, 3) & "." & Mid(pID, 14, 2)

    Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementById("SearchText").Value = pID    'Put id in text box
    Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementById("HidParcelNo").Value = hiddenPID  'Put hidden pID in the hidden element
    Doc.getElementById("Iframe1").contentDocument.getElementById("Search").Click  'search button

End Sub

Sub WaitForIE()
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

I wanted to get data from a webpage which accessed by following steps:

1. Visit url: http://eringcapture.jccal.org/caportal/CAPortal_MainPage.aspx
2. Click on `Search your Real Property. Click Here`    which is at the bottom of that web page.
3. Enter parcel #: 22002240080330
4. Click on the link of the first result

Now the tables are in different frames and I can't figure out how I can access the table data.

Comment: Why not to use XHR instead pf IE?

Comment: @omegastripes because I have no idea how to implement that here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to visit that url, clicking etcetera, you could just do a GET request to this url:

```
Const tablesUrl As String = "http://eringcapture.jccal.org/caportal/CA_PropertyTaxParcelInfo.aspx?ParcelNo=*PARCELNO*&TaxYear=*TAXYEAR*"
Const summaryUrl As String = "http://eringcapture.jccal.org/caportal/CA_PTSummary.aspx?ParcelNum=*PARCELNO*&RecordYear=*TAXYEAR*"
Dim url As String

Sub genOP()
    'Just a sample sub, use breakpoint to see what you get after navigating the urls
    Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    taxYear = 2017
    parcelNo = "22+00+22+4+008+033.000" 'you should recreate that dinamically based on the parcel

    'This for both tables url with header and select year box
    url = Replace(Replace(tablesUrl, "*PARCELNO*", parcelNo), "*TAXYEAR*", taxYear)
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate url

   'this for the tax/summary tables only
    url = Replace(Replace(summaryUrl, "*PARCELNO*", parcelNo), "*TAXYEAR*", taxYear)
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate url
End Sub
```

Then you can easy reach the table data with the **.getElementsByTagName("td")** method of the IE object and check if in the .innerHtml there is the data you need, without iterating through a lot of nested item.